# Connect a QListWidget selection with another QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

> **edit**
>   SOLVED, i just forgot to initialize `found_users`

I have two QListWidget into a single window.
The one on the left is the list of all the users of my database.
The one on the right displays a subset of accounts related to a query result.
I want the selection on the right to be reflected on the left.
For example if i have on the left

> usr1
>   usr2
>   usr3
>   usr4

and I select "usr3" on the right list, it should be trigger the selection of "usr3" on the left.

Here's the code:
.h

```
class win_admin : public QWidget{  
    Q_OBJECT  
private:  
    QListWidget* all_users;  
    QListWidget* found_users;  
public:  
[...]  
public slots:  
    void send_to_main_list();  
[...]  
}
```

.cpp

```
connect (found_users, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(send_to_main_list()));
[...]
void win_admin::send_to_main_list() {
    QString usn=found_users->currentItem()->text();
    int i=0;
    while (i<all_users->count() && all_users->item(i)->text()!=usn) {
        ++i;
    }
    if (i<all_users->count()) if (i<all_users->count()) all_users->setCurrentRow(i);
}
```

that's not working for me when i select something on the right they say:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::itemSelectionChanged() to win_admin::send_to_main_list()
```

i hope, the info i gave was enought.

Comment: Did you initialize `found_users`?

Comment: Oh, you are right, i just forgot that.
Edited on top with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get shows the reason why `connect()` call has failed.

`QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::itemSelectionChanged() to win_admin::send_to_main_list()`

It shows that sender `QListWidget* found_users` passed to `connect()` call is null.

You should probably have forgotten to initialize `found_users`.